# Running Prometheus in a jhipster application using docker compose is down

Tags: prometheus, jhipster, monitoring

I run my applications generated by jhipster using the command docker-compose  up -d but when i go to prometheus i see that my application is down whereas in jhipster registry my applications are up!

can anyone tell me why this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: i edited the post. I cannot access to urls of my application when i run the apps with docker compose command? why?

Comment: I suppose that by running 2 docker compose files, your containers are in different networks by default and so cannot communicate with each other. Please read https://tjtelan.com/blog/how-to-link-multiple-docker-compose-via-network/

Comment: is this related to the fact that jhipster generates for every application a docker folder? because what i have done is i have created an other folder and run "jhipster docker-compose " command and i has generated a general configuration for my project including images for every app

Comment: Yes probably because the docker compose default project name which is used for network is the name of the folder where the yml files are. Although you can override it using a `.env` file